# Linux echo byte array to serial port

Tags: linux, hex

I would like to echo an array of bytes from the linux terminal to serial port. Have already seen this [Sending bytes to serial port from UNIX command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817313/sending-bytes-to-serial-port-from-unix-command-line) and from that deduced the command will be something like the following:

```
printf '%b' '\x9c8684a4624000a0b2668a84400003f00301000000048ab0c0' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To debug the ideia I redirected it to a file  with

```
printf '%b' '\x9c8684a4624000a0b2668a84400003f00301000000048ab0c0' > file.raw
```

and checked the file with hexedit. But so I've found that ASCII values were been written instead.

In the end I expect the following in the file:

```
9c 86 84 a4 62 40 00 a0 b2 66 8a 84 40 00 03 f0 03 01 00 00 00 04 8a b0 c0
```

Comment: Do you have to put \x before every single byte?

Comment: Is `printf '%b' '\x9c\x86\x84'` etc the thing you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly @Sukces Elektroniki!